# GAVC search in Artifactory doesn't take classifiers into account

Tags: java, deployment, artifactory

we experienced this issue working with Artifactory:

requested artifacts: ".../search/gavc?g=c2mon.c2mon-deploy&a=c2mon-srv-tim2&v=1.2.1-SNAPSHOT&c=tim2"

Artifactory does not respond correctly to the search request. It delivers all classifiers instead of only “tim2” (first two are wrongly delivered) :

c2mon.c2mon-deploy c2mon-srv-tim2 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT jar

c2mon.c2mon-deploy c2mon-srv-tim2 sources 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT jar

c2mon.c2mon-deploy c2mon-srv-tim2 tim2 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT tar.gz

The problem appears for artifacts with extension tar.gz only. Somehow combination version+classifier works as classifier (e.g. 1.0.1-tim2) in such cases. Unfortunately this solution produces a lot of workaround in our deployment script.

We are looking for better solution. Does anybody have the same or similar problems with deploying non-standard targets to Artifactory?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to reproduce it, [it's a bug](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5909). You're invited to vote-n-watch.

Comment: Voted. Reproduced in 5.8.3. gavc filter works for `tests` classifier, but doesn't for `schema` classifier